# Simple way to replace specific HTML substring in HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have

```
OldPattern = <div style="page-break-after: always"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

in some master Html.

I want to replace with:

```
NewPattern = <br> <br style="page-break-after: always;" />
```

I believe I can do something like:

```
NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace(OldPattern, NewPattern)
```

Of course the assignment will not work due to the double quotes etc. This is where I get stuck.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes like so `\"`. This works well:

```
string oldPattern = "<div style=\"page-break-after: always\"><span style=\"display: none;\">&nbsp;</span></div>";
string newPattern = "<br> <br style=\"page-break-after: always;\" />";
NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace(oldPattern, newPattern);
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick response.

Comment: Well @SamJolly , better than a thank you, accept the answer you prefer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape double quotes inside a string. You can do it in the following ways:

In normal strings:

Use the backslash (`\`) character before the character to be escaped:

```
string escaped = "\"Hello\"";
```

This will assign `"Hello"` to escaped.

In verbatim literals:

Use two double quotes within the string like this:

```
string escaped = @"""Hello""";
```

This will assign `"Hello"` to escaped.

**In your case:**

```
OldPattern = "<div style=\"page-break-after: always\"><span style=\"display: none;\">&nbsp;</span></div>"
NewPattern = "<br> <br style=\"page-break-after: always;\" />"
NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace(OldPattern, NewPattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use @ in front of a string and use "" for escaping , wich makes the code more readable

```
   OldPattern = @"<div style=""page-break-after: always""><span style=""display: none;"">&nbsp;</span></div>" 
   NewPattern = @"<br> <br style=""page-break-after: always;"" />"
   NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace(OldPattern, NewPattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
string OldPattern = string.Format("<div style=\"{0}\"><span style=\"{1}\"</span></div>", "page-break-after: always", "display: none;");
string NewPattern = string.Format("<br><br style=\"{0}\"/>","page-break-after: always;");

NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace(oldPattern, newPattern);
```